# How to connect and query PostgreSQL RDS from EC2 using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds

How to use NodeJS to create connection from EC2 to remote RDS (PostgreSQL) and query it?

I have this code but currently does not work (how exactly connection string should look like including password?):

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://username:@db.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/testdb";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM t1");
//fired after last row is emitted

query.on('row', function(row) {
    console.log(row);
});

query.on('end', function() {
    client.end();
});
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you need a password: `postgres://username:password@db.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/testdb`

Comment: this worked..thanks! Do we need to close connection at the end somehow? (or is automatic with above approach)

Comment: I'd recommend not using a bare url - see the pooling example here with config: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres#pooling-example. Note that setting `idleTimeoutMillis` will close a timed-out client automatically.

Comment: Yes you need to close connections explicitly, otherwise your Postgres will reach maximum connections number soon -- check current sessions with `select * from pg_stat_activity;`.

Comment: Great, thanks for help.. @randnum - I start checking 'pooling-example'. Do you know if this line of code could be simply replaced with regular SQL query instead of parametrized?  "client.query('SELECT $1::text as name', ['brianc'], function (err, result) {"

Answer (score 0):

```js
const connUrl = postgres://{username}:{passoword}@{endpoint}:{port}/{database}
```